# Looping through json data using angular and filling in missing values

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, loops, duplicate-data

So I have this problem where I am populating a range input using data coming from an external json file...

So basically the data has a bunch of objects with an array of values and text in each object.  But some of the objects don't have consecutive values to loop though and output on the range slider like this:

```
var someObj = [
  {
    value: 1,
    text: 'A'
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    text: 'B'
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    text: 'C'
  },
  {
    vaule: 5,
    text: 'D'
  },
  {
    value: 6,
    text: 'E'
  },
  {
    vaule: 8,
    text: 'F'
  }
];
```

Notice that Value: 4 and value: 7 are missing, this can change too, in some objects value: 11 and value: 13 are missing too for example.

So basically what i need to achieve is to loop through each object and if there are values missing to add the value in and duplicate the text value from the value before so for example...

```
var someObj = [
  {
    value: 1,
    text: 'A'
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    text: 'B'
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    text: 'C'
  },
  {
    vaule: 5,
    text: 'D'
  },
  {
    value: 6,
    text: 'E'
  },
  {
    vaule: 8,
    text: 'F'
  }
];
```

Would become

```
var someObj = [
  {
    value: 1,
    text: 'A'
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    text: 'B'
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    text: 'C'
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    text: 'C'
  },
  {
    vaule: 5,
    text: 'D'
  },
  {
    value: 6,
    text: 'E'
  },
  {
    vaule: 7,
    text: 'E'
  },
  {
    vaule: 8,
    text: 'F'
  }
];
```

Is this possible and if so how on earth would i go about it please??

thanks in advance

Comment: Do your value will have incremental ? (1,2,3,4,5,6)

Comment: So the array is incremented but may have values missing and i want to create a new object which has all the values incremented and the ones that were missing before to be basically filled in and the text to duplicate the previous one so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i=0;
do{
if(someObj[i].value!=i+1){
    var obj = {}
    debugger;
    obj['value']= i+1;
    obj['text']= someObj[i-1].text;
    someObj.splice(i,0,obj);
}
i++;

}while(i<someObj.length);
```

refer this one :https://jsfiddle.net/cw5kkpgu/

Comment: change the answer. please refer it.

Comment: So we love your solutuion and it definatley works but we have found out that actually the data may start with various numbers and we need the script to increment up from the lowest number to the highest number and not start from 0

Comment: We did think about setting var i = the lowest value but this seems to increment every say 3rd value or what ever the lowest value is....

Any ideas on how to capture the lowest value and increment from their instead of 0?

Comment: Ok think we cracked it, fiddle here which is starting and ending on the correct percentage vale http://jsfiddle.net/guideveloper/xnaqtq9y/11/

Answer (score 1):

Get the last object value like

```
var someObjLength = someObj[someObj.length-1].value;
```

And

```
for(i = 0; i < someObjLength-1; i++) {

    if(someObj[i].value != (i+1)){

        someObj.splice(i, 0, {value: i+1, text: someObj[i-1].text})

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I actually finally have solved it now, sorry didn't fully understand initially what you were after but here's the Plunker for it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/n1tSfj2YJMeBZNZCSAF3?p=preview

Please confirm if it is :)

The crux of it is:

```
$scope.loop = function(){
  var previousText = '';
  var previousValue = '';
  var newObject = [];

  angular.forEach($scope.someObj, function(object){

    if(object.value == 1){
      newObject.push(object);
      previousText = object.text;
      previousValue = object.value;
      console.log("value:" + previousValue + " | Text:" + previousText);
    }
    else {
      if(object.value != (previousValue + 1)){
        while (object.value != (previousValue + 1)){
            previousValue += 1;
            newObject.push({ value: previousValue, text: previousText})

            console.log("value:" + previousValue + " | Text:" + previousText);
        }
      }
      else{
            newObject.push(object);
            previousValue = object.value;

            console.log("value:" + previousValue + " | Text:" + previousText);
      }

      previousText = object.text;
    }

  });

  // Add the last value as it's always missed
  newObject.push($scope.someObj[$scope.someObj.length - 1])

  $scope.someObj = newObject;
}
```

Comment: This is kinda what I'm looking for but in the data the last value is 11 so when you click push me there needs to be a new object with all 11 steps and the ones missing filled in but this example seems to keep the amount of steps it has and reorders the values.

Comment: bukke hari prasad is a much better solution

Answer (score 0):

I have created a js function to complete the missing objects. 
Let me know if it works.

```
function completeObject(someObj)
{
    var otherObj = [];
    for(var obj in someObj)
    {
      otherObj[someObj[obj]['value']] = someObj[obj];
    }

    var j = 0;
    for(var i =1 ; i <= someObj[someObj.length-1]['value'];i++)
    {
      if(otherObj[i] === undefined)
      {
        var obj = {}
        obj['value']= i;
        obj['text']= otherObj[j]['text'];
        otherObj.push(obj);
      }
      else
      {
        j = i ;
      }
    }

    return otherObj;
}
```